# CMake variable containing path to binary in Conan dev tool package

Tags: cmake, conan

I have a CMake based project which needs to convert test data using an executable `convert.exe`. Conversion is done by calling a custom macro defined in convert.cmake:

```
set( ConversionCall ${ConvertExecutablePath} -i -w -k)

macro( convert_test_data InputFilename )
   set( OutputFilename ${InputFilename}.converted)
   add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${OutputFilename}
    COMMAND ${ConversionCall} ${InputFilename} ${OutputFilename}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${InputFilename}
   )
endmacro (convert_test_data)
```

The convert executable is an existing binary provided by a Conan dev tool package using the following recipe cloning a git project containing `convert.exe` in a folder named `tools` and pack it into a `bin` folder in the Conan package.

```py
from conans import ConanFile, tools

class ConvertConan(ConanFile):
    name = "convert"
    version = "6.7.9"
    settings = "os"
    no_copy_source = True
    description="Provides the test data conversion tool."

    def build(self):
        self.run("git clone https://myrepo")

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*", src="myrepo/tools", dst="bin", keep_path=False)
```

Due to the generic name `convert.exe` I would prefer to assign the path of `convert.exe` to the CMake variable `ConvertExecutablePath` in the macro given above instead of appending it to the system path environment variable. How and where can I define `ConvertExecutablePath` so that it points to the `convert.exe` provided by the Conan package?

I had a look at https://docs.conan.io/1/devtools/create_installer_packages.html using the path approach and also https://docs.conan.io/en/1.7/integrations/cmake/find_packages.html for generating  a custom CMake but failed in both cases.

Comment: where does it get packaged to? is `bin/` anywhere under the source tree of the project, or the build tree of the CMake-generated buildsystem? If so, you can just use `set(ConvertExecutablePath "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/...")` or `set(ConvertExecutablePath "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/...")`. Otherwise, you can look into using [`find_program`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html)

Comment: The convert.exe is not packed under the source tree. The conanfile.txt of the CMake based project lists convert/6.7.9 in the [requires] section. Hence, the convert conan package is installed in a subdirectory of a .conan directory containing a hash based directory name. Furthermore, the location of the .conan folder can be chosen arbitrarily so that a specific path cannot be assumed in order to use `find_program`.

Comment: You would need to create a cmake module with that custom variable, add the module with ``cpp_info.set_property("cmake_build_modules")``, and then if it is a ``tool_requires`` in the consumer side, use ``CMakeDeps.build_context_activated`` and ``CMakeDeps.build_context_build_modules`` (https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/tools/cmake/cmakedeps.html#build-context-build-modules) so it can be loaded with ``find_package()``.

Comment: You are also looking at very old documentation, you should be checking the latest 1.59 (not 1.7), or preferably the Conan 2.0 docs

Comment: Thank you for your answer dodri. I have to use Conan 1.58 and am sorry to say that I did not succeed following your outline solution and the Conan documentation. What I tried so far is to add
```python
  def generate(self):
     cmake = CMakeDeps(self)
     cmake.build_context_activated = ["MyCustomModule"]
     cmake.build_context_build_modules = ["MyCustomModule"]
     cmake.generate()

  def package_info(self):
     self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_build_modules","MyCustomModule")
```
to the recipe. But MyCustomModule cannot be found in the consumer using `tool_requires`.